# Docker build with problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke

Tags: docker

I kept receiving the error below when i try to build my dockerfile. i am using docker version 'Docker version 20.10.7, build f0df350'. in Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS.

I have tried apt update but still the same.

```
iotsvr@ncku-iottalk:~/travel/database-server$ sudo docker build -t travel_db_server:v0 .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  240.1MB
Step 1/13 : FROM tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi:python3.10-slim
 ---> 007d6d4403ee
Step 2/13 : WORKDIR /src
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 742703aa93fe
Step 3/13 : COPY internal ./internal
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 809c799446cd
Step 4/13 : COPY models ./models
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 43cb58ec68d1
Step 5/13 : COPY routers ./routers
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 73f22a59dede
Step 6/13 : COPY requirements.txt .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 137e7a732811
Step 7/13 : COPY main.py .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 63b578439414
Step 8/13 : RUN apt-get update && apt install -y libmariadb-dev
 ---> Running in cdaeea1e65cd
Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease [151 kB]
Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease [52.1 kB]
Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security InRelease [48.0 kB]
Get:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm/main amd64 Packages [8906 kB]
Get:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates/main amd64 Packages [4732 B]
Get:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security/main amd64 Packages [53.6 kB]
Fetched 9216 kB in 2s (4581 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke 'rm -f /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*.deb /var/cache/apt/*.bin || true'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt install -y libmariadb-dev' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

And this is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi:python3.10

WORKDIR /src

COPY internal ./internal
COPY models ./models
COPY routers ./routers
COPY requirements.txt .
COPY main.py .

RUN apt-get update && apt install -y libmariadb-dev
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
RUN pip install libmariadb

CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--reload", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8081"]

EXPOSE 8081
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm was running into the same error with the same version of Docker on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS.

I resolved this issue by using the bullseye image `python:3.11.5-slim-bullseye` instead